# SSTP VPN works but no Internet connection on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, vpn, sstp

I've established SSTP VPN client on my Ubuntu connecting to SSTP VPN server. 
I'm using http://sstp-client.sourceforge.net/ SSTP VPN client. And with this network manager plugin https://github.com/enaess/network-manager-sstp.

But I have the issue that I cannot access Internet when VPN is on. The same issue happens on Windows (with Windows built in VPN client) but there I can solve it using https://www.windowstechupdates.com/internet-connection-not-work-sstp-vpn-successfully-connect/.

I've tried selecting to "use connection only for its resources", but no Internet still. When I disable Automatic on Routes and select "use connection only for its resources" I have Internet but no VPN.

[image]

Anyone can help me how to allow simultaneous Internet connection?